# ¿Cómo graficar correctamente datos de un par de trading usando una función personalizada en Python? Relacionado con MatPlotLib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, depuración, plot, función-personalizada

Sucede que tengo la siguiente df llamada `df_trading_pair` la cual contiene datos recientes del par de trading `BTC/USDT`:

```
            Start Date  Open Price  High Price  Low Price  Close Price                End Date
0  2022-08-11 11:25:00    24512.25    24548.24   24507.78     24542.74 2022-08-11 11:29:59.999
1  2022-08-11 11:30:00    24543.54    24576.21   24524.36     24545.57 2022-08-11 11:34:59.999
2  2022-08-11 11:35:00    24545.08    24598.75   24541.00     24582.48 2022-08-11 11:39:59.999
3  2022-08-11 11:40:00    24583.40    24587.86   24552.52     24585.19 2022-08-11 11:44:59.999
4  2022-08-11 11:45:00    24586.40    24629.78   24578.02     24605.81 2022-08-11 11:49:59.999
5  2022-08-11 11:50:00    24605.81    24685.20   24597.07     24605.73 2022-08-11 11:54:59.999
6  2022-08-11 11:55:00    24605.73    24627.63   24533.40     24559.37 2022-08-11 11:59:59.999
7  2022-08-11 12:00:00    24559.37    24629.27   24546.00     24605.93 2022-08-11 12:04:59.999
8  2022-08-11 12:05:00    24606.71    24629.72   24592.89     24608.49 2022-08-11 12:09:59.999
9  2022-08-11 12:10:00    24608.49    24690.00   24582.14     24643.84 2022-08-11 12:14:59.999
10 2022-08-11 12:15:00    24644.79    24734.49   24602.37     24653.81 2022-08-11 12:19:59.999
11 2022-08-11 12:20:00    24653.81    24711.33   24635.80     24658.57 2022-08-11 12:24:59.999
12 2022-08-11 12:25:00    24658.57    24686.70   24593.81     24612.47 2022-08-11 12:29:59.999
13 2022-08-11 12:30:00    24613.83    24918.54   24531.05     24614.16 2022-08-11 12:34:59.999
14 2022-08-11 12:35:00    24617.40    24770.00   24567.41     24738.36 2022-08-11 12:39:59.999
15 2022-08-11 12:40:00    24737.14    24766.82   24640.00     24687.93 2022-08-11 12:44:59.999
16 2022-08-11 12:45:00    24690.17    24780.00   24687.21     24729.00 2022-08-11 12:49:59.999
17 2022-08-11 12:50:00    24730.52    24779.32   24698.54     24768.73 2022-08-11 12:54:59.999
```

Al ejecutar `df_trading_pair.dtypes`, la siguiente salida es retornada:

```
Start Date     datetime64[ns]
Open Price            float64
High Price            float64
Low Price             float64
Close Price           float64
End Date       datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Estoy interesado en graficar los datos de arriba para hacer que luzcan como la siguiente imagen:

[image: expected output]

Entonces, decidí escribir las siguientes líneas de código para ello:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def candlestick(t, o, h, l, c):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12), dpi=80)
    color = ["green" if close_price >= open_price else "red" for close_price, open_price in zip(c, o)]
    plt.bar(x=t, height=np.abs(o-c), bottom=np.min((o,c), axis=0), width=0.6, color=color)
    plt.bar(x=t, height=h-l, bottom=l, width=0.1, color=color)

candlestick(df_trading_pair["Start Date"],
                df_trading_pair["Open Price"],
                df_trading_pair["High Price"],
                df_trading_pair["Low Price"],
                df_trading_pair["Close Price"])
plt.grid(alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

En mi cabeza, eso funcionaba muy bien, pero luego de ejecutar dicha función, la realidad no pudo ser más vergonzosa:

[image: problem]

He venido para solicitar amablemente una retroalimentación y una posible alternativa/corrección a dicha función personalizada para obtener la salida deseada.

Creo que la sentencia `yaxis.set_label_position("right")` podría ser añadida al inicio de la función `candlestick` para establecer los valores del eje y a la derecha del gráfico, pero no sé cómo podría hacer que los valores del eje x muestren sólamente el formato de tiempo `HH:MM:00` (por ejemplo: `11:25:00`) de la columna `Start Date`.

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decidí irme por una alternativa:

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")

def klines_to_df(df_trading_pair):

    #drop unnecesary columns
    df_trading_pair.drop(5, inplace = True, axis=1)
    df_trading_pair.drop(7, inplace = True, axis=1)
    df_trading_pair.drop(8, inplace = True, axis=1)
    df_trading_pair.drop(9, inplace = True, axis=1)
    df_trading_pair.drop(10, inplace = True, axis=1)
    df_trading_pair.drop(11, inplace = True, axis=1)

    # Rename the column names for best practices
    df_trading_pair.rename(columns = { 0 : 'Start Date', 
                                       1 : 'Open Price',
                                       2 : 'High Price',
                                       3 : 'Low Price',
                                       4 :'Close Price',
                                       6 :'End Date',
                                      }, inplace = True)

    # Convert Unix Time values to actual dates
    df_trading_pair['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trading_pair['Start Date'], unit='ms')
    df_trading_pair['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trading_pair['End Date'], unit='ms')
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.astype({'Open Price': 'float'})
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.astype({'High Price': 'float'})
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.astype({'Low Price': 'float'})
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.astype({'Close Price': 'float'})

    return df_trading_pair

def set_DateTimeIndex(df_trading_pair):
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
    # Rename the column names for best practices
    df_trading_pair.rename(columns = { "Open Price" : 'Open',
                                       "High Price" : 'High',
                                       "Low Price" : 'Low',
                                       "Close Price" :'Close',
                              }, inplace = True)
    return df_trading_pair

#get historical klines
klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol="BTCUSDT", interval="5m", start_str = "1660235100000", end_str="1660240200000")

# Customize the df_trading_pair that stored klines
df_trading_pair = klines_to_df(pd.DataFrame(klines))
# Modify the previous df so the next lines of code run perfectly
df_trading_pair_date_time_index = set_DateTimeIndex(df_trading_pair)

# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh','dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
btc_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                            figratio=(10, 6),
                            type="candle",
                            style=s,
                            tight_layout=True,
                            datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                            ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                            returnfig=True)
# Add Title
axlist[0].set_title("BTC/USDT - 5m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy' )
```

**Salida:**

[image: Éxito]

Comment: si resolviste tu problema cierra la pregunta. el error del primer codigo es que graficaste de golpe muchos conjuntos de datos, el ancho de las barras es muy grande(0.6 es porcentual de 0 a 1) y para ahorrarte todo ese codigo tan enredado, te recomendaria no realizar la operacion de los datos en el codigo python si no que estos vengan listos en tu base de datos y simplemente llamarlos.